# Gaq push events not showing in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

We are using a custom tracking code to track events in UA, which was fine until now, but as there is a deadline to move all the events in GA4, I have already integrated the GA4 to the website, but I couldn't see those events there. Following is an example of an event I use.

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'EventCategory', 'EventAction', 'EventLabel']);

Homepage=Category , PretSmallBanJan2023Stars = Event name , Banner= Event label

e.g. - _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'HomePage', 'PretSmallBanJan2023Stars-CH', 'Banner']);

There are over 15k events like this that are on the current setup which I have to move before July, so if there is any way to keep the same setup and see data in GA4 it will be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider that in `GA4` there are no more `Category`, `Action` and `Label`.
Follow  [This Link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9744165#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) to move to `GA4`. Remember that there have been some major differences, as an example look at this [Comparing metrics: Google Analytics 4 vs Universal Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11986666?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article).
In order to define a `Custom Event` in  `GA4` follow [GA4 Custom Events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12229021?hl=en)

In order to define custom events you can use two methods:

1 - GTAG

2- DataLayer

I believe it would be easier if you use  the first one or `gtag.js API` to send info or events to Google Analytic API. However, it is subjected to change(so you might be obligated to change something or update something on and off when Google decides).

**1 - GTAG**

As it is described in this link [Set Up an Event for Website Apps](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/events?client_type=gtag) for GTAG,

> Before you begin:
>
> Create a Google Analytics 4 account and property Create a web data
> stream for your website Place the Google tag on your website It also
> assumes that you have the following:
>
> Access to your website source code The Editor role to the Google
> Analytics account

To send events to Google Analytics this API has one function called gtag(), and whenever you want to send an event to Google Analytics, you use the following syntax:

```
  gtag('event', '<event_name>', {
    <event_parameters>
   });
```

Finally, if you need the same metrics `Category`, `Action` and `Label` I suggest you to create `Custom Dimensions` for these three. So if you have an old-defined table in your Database, it is not going to change the fields or create loads to the developers. The documentation for creating `Custom Dimensions and Metrics` is [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en). Remember that it takes 48 hours for GA4 API to recognise your custom dimensions. There are some limitations as well that you can read at the link above.

**2- DataLayer**

In this method, you need to work with `GTM` or `Google Tag Manager`, as well.
To read more, you can follow this link [GTM](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/events?client_type=gtm).

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I will try it and keep you posted with the results